# wpf assign one color to another

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

In my XAML I have this:

```
<Color x:Key="VeryLightGrey">#fff0f0f0</Color> 
<Color x:Key="TabBackgroundColor">#fff0f0f0</Color>
```

I would love to have something like this:

```
<Color x:Key="TabBackgroundColor" Color="{StaticResource VeryLightGrey}"/>
```

I have tried various methods including this:

```
<StaticResource x:Key="TabBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="VeryLightGrey"/>
```

But my code become riddled with warning about:

"An object of type System.Wndows.StaticResourceExtention cannot be applied to a property that expects the type System.Windows.Media.Color"

Other posts say to ignore this warning, but it actually causes problems, so i cant.

Is there a better solution out there ?

Comment: What? why do you want to duplicate resources like that?

Comment: because i want to be able to assign verylightgrey to the tabbackground, not the number #fff etc. I also want the color to be defined as grey, not just the color brush. Its not a duplication really, it makes it easier for people to understand and also easier to change colors later

Comment: Not really. You seem to misunderstand how XAML resources work. Use Brushes as mentioned in @Emo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the color once and define multiple brushes that use the same color.

Use the Brushes for your UI Elements.

Comment: i cant uses brushed in all the UI elements I have, sometimes i must use Colors

Comment: @Andy - Please give me an example of a situation where you cannot use a brush.

Comment: <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource TabBackgroundColor}" Offset="0.5"/>  it has to use a Brush here, not a color

Comment: @andy this gradientstop is part of a gradientbrush. Just make multiple gradient brushes and refer to colors using StaticResource